# Is it still useful to use addslashes() when the mysql db is utf8?

Tags: mysql

I was using `addslashes` for my mysql queries on inputing new text
but apperantly addslashes caused me some strange chars appearing in the input... as i removed the `addslashes`, everything went fine again...

how come `addslashes` turn an apostrophe in â€™ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

addslashes is to sql injection prevention as a piece of wet toilet paper is to your PhD thesis - utterly useless.

Get a scalpel and surgically remove the knowledge of addslashes()'s existence from your brain, and use `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead.

it is precisely the fact that addslashes is NOT unicode aware that makes it completely and utterly useless these days.